# Matter.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events') in Events.trigger() when calling World.add()

Tags: javascript, p5.js, physics-engine, matter.js

```js
// matter.js modules 
let Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Mouse = Matter.Mouse, 
    MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;
    
// Game variables
let engine;
let world;
let renderer;

// Table variables
let table;
let pocketSize = 50;
let tableWidth = 500;
let tableHeight = 250; 

// Ball arrays
let reds = [];
let colours = [];
let pockets = [];

// Cue variables
let cueBall;
let cue;
let cueLength = 100;
let aiming = false; 

// Game state
let consecutiveColours = 0;

function setup() {

  // Canvas
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  
  // Engine
  engine = Engine.create(); 
  
  // Renderer
  renderer = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,    
    options: {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        wireframes: false
    }
  });

  // Table body
  table = Bodies.rectangle(width / 2, height / 2, tableWidth, tableHeight, { 
    isStatic: true 
  });
  World.add(world, table);

  // Table walls
  World.add(world, [
    Bodies.rectangle(width / 2, 50, width, 100, {isStatic: true}),
    Bodies.rectangle(width / 2, height - 50, width, 100, {isStatic: true}),   
    Bodies.rectangle(50, height / 2, 100, height, {isStatic: true}),
    Bodies.rectangle(width - 50, height / 2, 100, height, {isStatic: true})
  ]);
   
  // Pockets
  let pocketOpts = { isStatic: true, isSensor: true };
  pockets.push(Bodies.rectangle(width / 2, 50, pocketSize, pocketSize, pocketOpts));
  // Add other 5 pockets
  
  // Red balls
  for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    let ball = Bodies.circle(random(tableWidth / 4, tableWidth * 3 / 4), 
                            random(100, tableHeight - 50), 15, 
                            { friction: 0.05, 
                              restitution: 0.5 
                            });
    World.add(world, ball);
    reds.push(ball);
  }
  
  // Coloured balls  
  let colourOptions = { friction: 0.05, restitution: 0.5 }; 
  colours.push(Bodies.circle(tableWidth / 4, tableHeight / 2, 15, colourOptions));
  colours.push(Bodies.circle(tableWidth * 3/4, tableHeight / 2, 15, colourOptions));

  // Cue ball
  cueBall = Bodies.circle(tableWidth / 2, tableHeight - 30, 15, 
                          { friction: 0.05, 
                            restitution: 0.8});
  World.add(world, cueBall);                           

  // Mouse control
  let mouse = Mouse.create(renderer.canvas); 
  let mConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, { mouse: mouse });
  World.add(world, mConstraint);

  // Run renderer
  Render.run(renderer);
 
}

function draw() {

  // Background
  background(0, 128, 0);

  // Table  
  stroke(128);
  strokeWeight(2);  
  fill(100, 50, 0);
  rect(table.position.x - tableWidth / 2, 
        table.position.y - tableHeight / 2, 
        tableWidth, 
        tableHeight);
  
  // Balls
  for(let i = 0; i < reds.length; i++) {
    drawBall(reds[i]);
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
    drawBall(colours[i], 10);  
  }

  // Cue ball  
  drawBall(cueBall);
  
  // Cue 
  if (aiming) {
    drawCue();
  }

  // Collision messages  
  checkCueCollisions();
  
  // Update physics
  Engine.update(engine);

  // Remove pocketed reds
  reds = reds.filter(red => !red.isSensor);
  
}

// Ball function
function drawBall(ball, r = 15) {
 
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(255); 
  circle(ball.position.x, ball.position.y, r * 2);  
  pop();
   
}

// Cue rendering  
function drawCue() {

  let x = mouseX;
  let y = mouseY; 
  if (!onTable(x, y)) {
    x = cue.position.x; 
    y = cue.position.y;
  }
  
  push();
  stroke(128);
  strokeWeight(10); 
  line(x, y, x - cueLength * cos(cue.angle),  
        y - cueLength * sin(cue.angle)); 
  pop();
  
}

// Cue ball shot
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === ENTER) {
    aiming = true;
    cue = Bodies.rectangle(cueBall.position.x, cueBall.position.y, 100, 10);
    World.add(world, cue);
  }
}

// Collision messages
function checkCueCollisions() {

  // Implement collisions with balls and cushions
  
}

// Helper functions
function onTable(x, y) {

  return x >= 0 && x <= width &&  
         y >= 100 && y <= height - 100; 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

This is the code I have for a snooker game using the matter.js engine. I spent the last couple hours trying to figure out where the error is. Image attached is the error I got attempting to simulate the game. Could someone help me attempt to figure out the error? Only other script I have is the matter.js script

Expected the code to simulate, got this error instead[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTS8W.png)

Comment: You're not initializing `world` before passing it to `World.add`. You can easily find mistakes like this by debugging your code line by line or logging out values before function calls.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). That error could be pasted in as searchable text, and preferably added to the title so others with the same problem can find the answer. Also, most of this code isn't relevant to the error, so a [mcve] would be good to cut out noise and isolate the problem. `World` is deprecated so you shouldn't be using it anyway, unless you have good reason to be using an older MJS version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When debugging, you'll often have a wall of code like this, with no obvious entry point. The first step is to [isolate the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), either by rebuilding from scratch until you have a small chunk of code that reproduces the failure, or removing chunks of the full code until the problem goes away, then adding the last part back in. In this case, it's pretty clear that `draw()` isn't reached since the crash occurs in `setup()`, so you can remove any function unrelated to `setup()` outright.

Another approach, [pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691356/matter-js-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-events-in-events-trig/77693882#comment136967549_77691356), is printing the arguments to the failing function call which should make the problem clear.

Here's a minimal reproduction of the error:

```js
let world;

function setup() {
  const table = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    width / 2, height / 2, 10, 10
  );
  print({world}); // => {world: undefined}
  Matter.World.add(world, table);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

With such little code, and a clear error message, the problem should be pretty obvious. You're passing `undefined` as the first argument to `World.add()`. Instead, initialize `let world;` with `world = engine.world` (or pass `engine.world` directly into `World.add()`:

```js
let engine;
let world;
let table;

function setup() {
  engine = Matter.Engine.create();
  world = engine.world;
  table = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    width / 2, height / 2, 10, 10
  );
  Matter.World.add(world, table);
}

function draw() {
  // prove it's working
  frameRate(1);
  print(table.position);
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

That said, `World` is deprecated, so if you're using a recent version of Matter.js, use `Composite.add()` instead (I've also removed the intermediate `world` variable which isn't necessary):

```js
let engine;
let table;

function setup() {
  engine = Matter.Engine.create();
  table = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    width / 2, height / 2, 10, 10
  );
  Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, table);
}

function draw() {
  // prove it's working
  frameRate(1);
  print(table.position);
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I haven't checked the rest of your code, but if there are additional errors, you now have the tools to isolate and debug them one by one. When developing, it's a good idea to run your code often so you can catch errors as they appear. If you write a hundred lines without testing and verifying each piece as you go, it's likely that you'll accrue multiple errors which will be more difficult to find and debug than if you'd tackled them as they arose.